# How do I upload the file at a URL using XHRWebRequest?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

In a chrome extension I have a url stored as `ctx.srcUrl`.  I am trying to upload the file that the URL points to onto a server.  I can upload a `file` object using XHR with:

```
function uploadFile(file) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('upload', file)

    xhr.open('POST', 'https://endpoint.com/upload')
    xhr.withCredentials = true
    xhr.send(formData)
}
```

Where file is a Javascript `File` object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). I can also download an object using:

```
function downloadFile() {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
  request.open('GET', ctx.srcUrl, true)
  request.responseType = 'blob'
  
  request.onload = function() {
    // response is stored in `request.response`
  }
  request.send()
}
```

I'm struggling to work out how to link them up in an efficient manner however, preferably without keeping all of the response in memory at once (using streaming)?  The best way I can find of doing it is using `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` but that has a file limit of ~256MB and some files might be larger than that.

There must be a better way of doing this, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use fetch and [Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams) if available. Otherwise read to a blob, then call uploadFile from request.onload callback. Alternatively, for an advanced fallback, you can use an HTTP header to request only a small byte range and use chunked uploads. There may be an existing library for that.

Comment: Oooh, I can guarentee fetch being available.  I'll look into using that. @wOxxOm